# Выбор программы в bat файле

Tags: bat

Можно ли в bat-файле указать с помощью какой программы открывать прописанный файл?

Я запускаю файл, не имеющий разрешения и назначить какую-то программу по умолчанию мне соответственно не удается, поэтому каждый раз при запуске приходится выбирать с помощью чего открывать. В частности необходимо, чтобы прописанный файл открывался с помощью iexplorer.exe.

Comment: iexplorer.exe some.file.ext - не?

Comment: Ответ "программа" "файл".  например c:\windows\notepad.exe "мой файл.org"

Answer (score 2):

Как правило, консольным программам можно передавать открываемый файл через аргумент. Например:

```
> Notepad.exe index.html
```